# connecting wifi module to proxy based wifi

Tags: microcontroller, wifi

I have a wifi module with micro-controller , but my college wifi uses proxy, SO how can I program proxy credentials in my C program so that my wifi module connected to micro-controller can connect to wifi. My wifi connection requires only proxy (like 10.x.abs.pqr) and no username or password authentication.

Comment: What kind of proxy? Socks? Squid?

Comment: we have socks type of proxy network

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand the SOCKS protocol.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS

Then you need to implement that in your firmware.

Connecting the WiFi module to the access point is no different to any other access point.  Establishing the authentication, IP address, etc is all exactly as per normal.

The only change comes when you want to make a request to the internet.  Instead of making a direct request to the internet (say a HTTP "GET" request) you make a SOCKS request to the SOCKS proxy containing your request to the internet.

Comment: How do I implement a socks request ? Any tutorial or documentation I can read. preferably in C.

Comment: Everything you need to know is contained in the RFC. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1928